# Ultrawingrid - Row Appearance issue

Tags: appearance, ultrawingrid

I am facing an issue with the appearance of the rows. Basically, I have added 2 appearances one for BackColor and the other for Forecolor, in the InitilizeLayout and used the Backcolor appearance in InitilizeRow. It works fine till then.

But when I use the forecolor appearance on some specific rows click of a button, it changes the forecolor appearance of all rows of the grid.

I am using below code:

**InitializeLayout code:**

```
lRowColorAppereance = e.Layout.Appearances.Add("GridBackColor")
lRowColorAppereance.BackColor = Color.LightGray
lRowColorAppereance.FontData.Bold = DefaultableBoolean.True

lIsMasterDBAppereance = e.Layout.Appearances.Add("IsMasterDB")
lIsMasterDBAppereance.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
```

**InitializeRow code:**

```
e.Row.Appearance = grdData.DisplayLayout.Appearances("GridBackColor")
```

Now, on click of a button when I change the Forecolor of my 0th row to lIsMasterDBAppereance.ForeColor OR Color.DarkGreen using the following code, it changes the Forecolor of all of the rows to DarkGreen.

**Button click Event code:**

```
lugrAddedRow.Appearance.ForeColor = grdData.DisplayLayout.Appearances("IsMasterDB").ForeColor

OR

lugrAddedRow.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
```

But I don't want to change forecolor of all rows, I just need to change forecolor of some specific rows.

Can you please suggest If I am missing out something.

Comment: Can someone please have a look at it?

Comment: What is lugrAddedRow a reference to in your last code section? Also, InitializeRow will get hit any time the grid is refreshed (e.g. if the data binding tells the grid that the data has changed), so setting the appearance there may have unintended consequences. You may want to do that in the InitializeLayout.